# Can't get Set-Cookie property in Java

Tags: java, cookies, properties

I have a java method which should get Set-Cookie property for following login into webpage. But the **conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie")** does not return anything. Any advice?

```
  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

URL obj = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// default is GET
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

conn.setUseCaches(false);

// act like a browser
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "s-CZ,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
}
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();

// Get the response cookies

System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie")); //print for testing
setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

return response.toString();
```

Whole program: http://pastebin.com/3nB682L7

Anyone?..:-)

Comment: Do you have the raw output from the server to see that the Set-Cookie is actually sent? I hit a similar problem recently, and the cookie was marked HttpOnly, which are recently filtered by URLConnection.

Comment: I see that it is marked HttpOnly.. Is there any way how to copy the value with this settings?.:-)

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with URLConnection. You might have to use an alternative HTTP client.

Comment: Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent Java versions have "fixed" URLConnection to hide cookies that are marked HttpOnly, and I don't think there's a setting to disable that.  I would recommend using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).